# How can we Find Ip Address using Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, angular, operating-system, ip-address

```
const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [] });
     peerConnection.createDataChannel('');

     peerConnection.createOffer()
    .then((offer) => peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));

    peerConnection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
    if (event.candidate) {
      console.log(`Client's IP address is ${event.candidate.address}`);
     }
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to security and privacy concerns, you can't directly get a user's public IP address when JavaScript is running in a web browser. But you can use API calls to third-party sites to get the user's public IP address.

Here's how you can use JavaScript and an outside service to find the IP address:

**1. **Using a free service for IP API****

To get the public IP address, you can use a tool like ipify.

```js
fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data.ip);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error:', error);
    });
```

**2. Using WebRTC (Public IP Unreliable)**

WebRTC can be used to find out the user's private and maybe even public IP address. But this method doesn't guarantee a public IP, and it may reveal private IPs, which can be a privacy issue.

```js
function findIP(onNewIP) {
    var myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
    var pc = new myPeerConnection({
        iceServers: []
    }),
    noop = function() {},
    localIPs = {},
    ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
    key;

    function iterateIP(ip) {
        if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
        localIPs[ip] = true;
    }

    pc.createDataChannel("");

    pc.createOffer(function(sdp) {
        sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
            if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
            line.match(ipRegex).forEach(iterateIP);
        });

        pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
    }, noop);

    pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) {
        if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
        ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(iterateIP);
    };
}

findIP(ip => console.log('your IP is ' + ip));
```

Remember that if you use an external service like in the first way, you'll be dependent on that service's availability and may run into rate limits if you make too many requests in a short amount of time.

Comment: BY Using "api.ipify.org" we are only getting the server IP From which We are Using Internet. For Example IF we are Using Ethernet it will give us router IP Address and IF we are using WIFI then WE will get WIFI provider Machine Not of the local machine which we are using application.

Answer (score 0):

## Extract IP address from the candidate attribute

```
const ipAddress = event.candidate.candidate.split(' ')[4];
```

### Print IP address

```
console.log('IP address:', ipAddress);
```

Comment: we getting This " b15671cc-af68-41e6-8dd4-999ca8dd90e9.local " as output How to find   ip from this?

Comment: **Refer this:**

[link](https://stackdiary.com/tutorials/how-to-get-a-clients-ip-address-using-javascript/)

Comment: @RTC Connectoin give us only browser ip not machine

Comment: @Gopalk.Dwivedi there is not a concept for "IP per application". Nor is there a *single* IP for a machine. You should really clarify what are you looking for because this information is not directly exposed for a variety of reasons. Not the least of which is that it's not useful in a lot of situations.

Comment: I need client machine IP address( IPV4) from which the application is running @VLAZ